# Redirect results of dbcc sqlperf (logspace) to table

Tags: sql-server

I would like to redirect the results of dbcc sqlperf (logspace) to
a table. Tried insert into tab dbcc... but it did not work.

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `EXEC('')`

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpLOGSPACE ([Database Name] varchar(100), [Log Size (MB)] real, [Log Space Used (%)] real,  [Status] int)

INSERT INTO #TmpLOGSPACE 

EXEC('DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE);')

SELECT * FROM #TmpLOGSPACE
```